# Targeting JS named opening window in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, popup

I have a static HTML page which is named via JavaScript as such: `window.name = "windowname"`. This window opens a popup window, which contains links that target `windowname`.

This works as expected in IE/FF/Chrome and opens the links on the opener, however, Safari opens all links in a new window and not the opener.

Is anyone aware of a workaround or solution to this other than using JavaScript to open the links via `opener.location.href`? Is this a security `feature` of Safari or some other kind of issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Adding window.id didn't help the issue. What is strange is that testing this as a file works fine even in Safari, testing it on a server (localhost or remote) it does not work which leads me to believe it's some sort of security 'feature' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No resolution for this was ever found, I had to go with a method that didn't use pop-up windows due to this.

thanks for the effort.

b

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting the "id" attribute to the same string as the name.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you problem is without being able to see your code but the following worked for me in Safari 4:

**windowname:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>untitled</title>

</head>

<body onload="window.name='windowname'">
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('popup.html')">Open</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**popup:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>untitled</title>

</head>

<body>
<a href="http://google.com" target="windowname">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time - this will work for me as a first click, can you add another link to the popup and change the opener a second time? Again, it works fine locally, but not on a server...